# Can a webpage detect if an external display is connected?

Tags: javascript, screen-size, multiple-monitors

I know I can get the screen's dimensions with `window.screen.width` and `.height`, but this only gives me the display/screen which the browser is currently residing in. Is there a way to find if another monitor is connected?

Answer (score -2):

try `window.screen[2].width` `window.screen[2].height`

Comment: that would only work if the window stretched across the two screens, no?

Comment: When I try to index window.screen I get undefined - no matter which screen the window is on (or if it stretches across both)